# How to use same instance of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext in whole App?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using `Spring JDBCTemplate + Java` example. In this project, I need to use below code many times in my StudentDetailsLoader, UserDetailsLoader, AdminDetailsLoader and VendorDetailsLoader classes and in many classes to load respective class beans.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Is there any way we just create in one place and call its singleton instance wherever we need? Please guide.

Comment: Use some kind of static holder for it. However, typically, the entirety of your app would live within the context. No other part, except for your `main` method, should really need access to the `ApplicationContext` directly.

Comment: You've tagged `spring-mvc`. I'm assuming you're running through a Servlet container. There's very little for you to need access to the `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Bean and simply call instance of the bean

```
public class AppContext {
    public static ApplicationContext getAppContext(){
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    }
}
```

The bean

```
<bean id="appContext" class="com.common.rest.AppContext" />
```